# captureOutput is not being called when adding both videoDataOutput and audioDataOutput

Tags: ios, swift, video-capture, avcapturesession, avcapturephotooutput

**The goal**: Create a `VideoRecordingManager`.
It will be responsible for presenting the live preview, capture the video with audio and via a delegate method inform the relevant vc that a frame was captured and can be processed.

**The issue**: `captureOutput` from the `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` is not being called.

**Current status**: The live preview is working as should, I can what's being captured from my front camera on the previewView. But the breakpoint inside the captureOutput() is not being hit.
However (!) - if I comment out everything related to the audioInput and audioOutput in the `configureSessionVideoAndAudio()` - the `captureOutput` does get called!

**My code**:

```
class OAVideoRecordingManager: NSObject,
                           AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate,
                           AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate,
                           AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizerDelegate {

var delegate: VideoRecordingDelegate?

// MARK: - Live Preview
/** The UIView on which the LivePreview of the video will be shown to the user */
var previewView: UIView
/** Flag representing whether we are currently presenting the LivePreview to the user */
fileprivate var isShowingLivePreview = false
/** The AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer which will be added on top of videoPhotoPreviewView. */
fileprivate var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?


// MARK: - Voice
fileprivate var audioSharedSession: AVAudioSession?
fileprivate var urlAudioFile: URL?


// MARK: - Video
/** Flag responsible for starting and stopping the capturing. Represents the capturing status - on or off */
fileprivate var isRecordingVideo: Bool = false
/** Handles the media capture */
fileprivate var captureSession : AVCaptureSession?
fileprivate var videoWriter: AVAssetWriter!
fileprivate var videoWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!
fileprivate var audioWriterInput: AVAssetWriterInput!

/** The video result of the recording */
fileprivate lazy var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
/** The audio result of the recording */
fileprivate lazy var audioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
/** Synchronizes the data output from video & audio, ensuring that the data remains synchronized. */
var outputSynch: AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer!
/** Timestamp to synchronize the video frames with the corresponding audio samples  */
fileprivate var sessionAtSourceTime: CMTime?
private var _filename = ""


init(previewView: UIView, delegate: VideoRecordingDelegate) {
    self.previewView = previewView
    self.delegate = delegate
}

func setupRecordingManager() throws {
    try setupVoice()
    try setupWriter()
    sessionAtSourceTime = nil
}

/** Set up the URL for an audio file within the NSTemporaryDirectory and configure the shared AVAudioSession for recording */
fileprivate func setupVoice() throws {
    urlAudioFile =  URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("ix_audio.wav")
    audioSharedSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
    guard let _ = audioSharedSession else {
        print("Error: Unable to access the shared audio session.")
       throw NSError()
    }
    
    try audioSharedSession!.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.record)
}

/** Init AVAssetWriter with configured video and audio + init the writing process for the writer. Does NOT actually start capturing, just setup */
fileprivate func setupWriter() throws {
    
    videoWriter = nil
    
    // Generate a unique filename
    _filename = UUID().uuidString
    let videoPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("\(_filename).mp4")
    
    videoWriter = try AVAssetWriter(url: videoPath, fileType: AVFileType.mp4)
    
    // Add video input
    let videoOutputSettings: [String: Any] = [
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
        AVVideoWidthKey: previewView.bounds.width,
        AVVideoScalingModeKey: AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,
        AVVideoHeightKey: previewView.bounds.height,
        AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [
            AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: 2300000,
        ],
    ]
    videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)
    videoWriterInput.mediaTimeScale = CMTimeScale(bitPattern: 600)
    videoWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    if videoWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput) {
        videoWriter.add(videoWriterInput)
    }
    
    
    // Add audio input
    let audioOutputSettings: [String: Any] = [
        AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
        AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey: 64000,
    ]
    audioWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioOutputSettings)
    audioWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    if videoWriter.canAdd(audioWriterInput) {
        videoWriter.add(audioWriterInput)
    }
    
    videoWriter.startWriting() // Ready to start writing file when ordered to
}

@MainActor
fileprivate func initiateCaptureSession() throws {
    
    if captureSession == nil {
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        if captureSession!.canSetSessionPreset(.hd1280x720) {
            captureSession!.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
        } else {
            throw NSError()
        }
    }
    
    try configureSessionVideoAndAudio()
    captureSession?.startRunning()
}

/** Set up a capture session with audio and video data outputs, define delegates and init a synchronizer for the data outputs */
@MainActor
fileprivate func configureSessionVideoAndAudio() throws {
    
    guard let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio),
          let videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front),
          let session = captureSession
    else {
        throw NSError()
    }

    // Disable automatic audio session configuration to create our own
    session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false
    session.beginConfiguration()

    // Add input devices -
    // Add microphone to the session
    let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice)
    if captureSession!.canAddInput(audioInput) {
        captureSession!.addInput(audioInput)
    }
    // Add camera to the session
    let videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
    if captureSession!.canAddInput(videoInput) {
        captureSession!.addInput(videoInput)
    }

    // Add outputs -
    // Set up video data output
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.cvcamrecorder.record-video.data-output")
    videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = false
    if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
        session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    }
    // Set up audio data output
    if session.canAddOutput(audioDataOutput) {
        audioDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
        session.addOutput(audioDataOutput)
    }


    // Commit the configuration
    session.commitConfiguration()


    // Initialize the synchronizer after adding outputs to the session
    if session.outputs.contains(audioDataOutput) && session.outputs.contains(videoDataOutput) {
        outputSynch = AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer(dataOutputs: [videoDataOutput, audioDataOutput])
        outputSynch.setDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    }
}



@MainActor
@objc func startShowingLivePreview() throws {
    
    if !isShowingLivePreview && isHavePermission(for: .video) && isHavePermission(for: .audio) {
        try initiateCaptureSession()
        setupVideoPreviewLayer()
        isShowingLivePreview = true
        
        delegate?.livePreviewStartedShowing()
    }
}

private func setupVideoPreviewLayer() {
    guard let captureSession else { return }
    
    let previewLayerRect = previewView.bounds
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer!.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer!.bounds = previewLayerRect
    previewLayer!.position = CGPoint(x: previewLayerRect.midX, y: previewLayerRect.midY)
    previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation  = .portrait
    
    previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
}

@objc func stopShowingLivePreview() {
    
    if isShowingLivePreview {
        isShowingLivePreview = false
        previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        captureSession?.stopRunning()
        captureSession = nil
        
        delegate?.livePreviewStoppedShowing()
    }
}


/** A delegate (AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate) method that is called whenever a new video FRAME is captured to allow analysis of the frame if needed.
 Functions also starts the videowriter to create the final video. */
public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    
    if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) {
        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
            
            if isRecordingVideo {
                // Capture video and audio in one
                if sessionAtSourceTime == nil {
                    //Start writing
                    sessionAtSourceTime = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
                    videoWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: sessionAtSourceTime!)
                }
            }
            
            delegate?.analyzeVideoFrameOutput(with: pixelBuffer)
        }
    }
}

/** A delegate method that is called whenever synchronized data is captured.
 Check the synchronized data, make sure it wasn't dropped and append it to the writer input */
func dataOutputSynchronizer(_ synchronizer: AVCaptureDataOutputSynchronizer,
                            didOutput synchronizedDataCollection: AVCaptureSynchronizedDataCollection
) {
    guard isRecordingVideo, let _ = sessionAtSourceTime else { return }

    processSynchronizedData(synchronizedDataCollection,
                            for: videoDataOutput,
                            using: &videoWriterInput,
                            debugName: "video")
    processSynchronizedData(synchronizedDataCollection,
                            for: audioDataOutput,
                            using: &audioWriterInput,
                            debugName: "audio")
}
private func processSynchronizedData(_ synchronizedDataCollection: AVCaptureSynchronizedDataCollection,
                             for dataOutput: AVCaptureOutput,
                             using writerInput: inout AVAssetWriterInput,
                             debugName: String) {
    
    guard let syncedData = synchronizedDataCollection.synchronizedData(for: dataOutput) as? AVCaptureSynchronizedSampleBufferData else { return }
    guard !syncedData.sampleBufferWasDropped else {
        print("Dropped \(debugName) data")
        return
    }
    
    let sampleBuffer = syncedData.sampleBuffer
    if isRecordingVideo && writerInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        writerInput.append(sampleBuffer)
    }
}

func isHavePermission(for type: MediaPermissionType) -> Bool {
    let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: type.asMediaType())
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}}
```

**I've searched in these threads**:

1- [captureOutput from AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73615100/captureoutput-from-avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate-is-not-being-cal)

2- [captureOutput function isn't called using setSampleBufferDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628283/captureoutput-function-isnt-called-using-setsamplebufferdelegate)

3- [captureOutput not being called by AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573039/captureoutput-not-being-called-by-avcaptureaudiodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate)

4- [captureOutput() function is never called swift4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56650493/captureoutput-function-is-never-called-swift4)

Nothing solves my issue.

Would appreciate any help!